# RecursiveDirectoryIterator gives exception

Tags: php, scandir

RecursiveDirectoryIterator gives  Unexpected Value Exeception

```
$path= WEB."sync_content/offer/";
  $files = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
                new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
                RecursiveIteratorIterator::LEAVES_ONLY
            );

 foreach ($files as $name => $file) {
        $fn=$file->getFilename();
        if($fn!='.' && $fn!='..' && !is_dir($fn)) {
            $filePath = $file->getRealPath();
            $zip->addFile($filePath,$fn);   
        }
    }
```

And the error is:

> fatal error
>   Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(http://localhost/base/sync_content/offer/): failed to open dir: not implemented in C:\xampp\htdocs\base\classes\campaigns.class.php 249

Comment: TRY to give full path directly (hardcode it) and check is it working or not?

Comment: i tried ... but still the same error... :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be accessing the local storage using a URL ("http://localhost/..."), which won't work for RecursiveIteratorIterator. You may be better off setting `$path` to point directly to the local directory instead, like `$path = "/full/path/to/base/sync_content/offer/"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `try` `catch` for specific error msg in my case its `permission issues`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot go with RecursiveIteratorIterator for web pages. This can be applied to local directories only. The URL is not directory, that's why it's failing.

Comment: there are images inside "http://localhost/base/sync_content/offer/"    this folder   like 1.jpg   2.jpg  so  how can we go ahead in such situation

Comment: Sadly you can't. The class constructor is accepting only paths, not urls.