# Create multidimensional array containing directory listing in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, list, directory

I am trying to scan a http directory and get all folders, subfolders and files in a multidimensional array.
The idea is to use the array to create a menu and then browse and list folder contents based on which menu item is clicked.
I am using this code for reading the parent directory:

```
$GLOBALS['website'] = 'http://thewebsite.com/catalog/';

        function readmenuitems($item=""){
            $website = $GLOBALS['website'];
            $webfolder = $website.$item;
            $result = array();

            $html = file_get_html($webfolder);
            foreach($html->find('a') as $element){
                array_push($result, $element->href);
            }
            return $result;
        }

        $allitems = readmenuitems();
```

The function file_get_html() is from here: http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/

I made the first level of the menus like this but my knowledge in php is not enough to make it go inside the directories and loop while there are other subdirectories and files.
The whole thing should work in Wordpress.

I will appreciate any help or good idea how to solve this problem :)

Thank you!

Comment: You should give the `RecursiveDirectoryIterator` a try http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php

Comment: I get the following error when using it: 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(http://thewebsite.com/catalog/): failed to open dir: not implemented'

Comment: look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491037/recursivedirectoryiterator-gives-exception maybe that helps